# Write to file in a schedule task Python

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script that crawls the web every 10secs (scheduling task), and i need that data to be saved in a file format. Problem is that I am only able to save the last set of data. I guess the other data is overwritten by the schedule task.

```
import sched
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
url = 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL'

def execute_async_task(address):
    requested = requests.get(address)
    data = requested.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll('span', {'id': 'yfs_l84_aapl'})[0]:
        if link:
            f = open('PlotData.txt', 'w')
            f.write("stock_price:"+str(link)+"\n")
            time.sleep(0.05)
            scheduler.enter(10, 1, execute_async_task, (url,))


scheduler.enter(0, 1, execute_async_task, (url,))
scheduler.run()
```

I am relatively new, to python.

Comment: Won't this create too many files? I just want a effective method to write to same file!

Comment: `open('PlotData.txt','a')` will open the file in append mode which will not overwrite the file as in `w` mode you can rotate the file after the file has reached a certain size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `f = open('PlotData.txt', 'a')` instead of `f = open('PlotData.txt', 'w')`

'w': Overwrite the existing file

'a': Append to the existing data in the file

Comment: Not at all :-) Feel free to validate my answer :-)